# How do I output information from my Method to the user as a table?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, file-io

For my program, I'm trying to use data from a file that will take the numbers(which stand for Celsius) and use them to calculate standard deviation/convert to Fahrenheit. I've already created the methods for the calculation but I'm not sure what is the right way of outputting the information from those methods to the user when I run the code.

I've tried:

- sDeviation(celsius);
- double fDeviation = sDeviation(celsius);

[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/NexusRei/115560c080c57ef4a081b9607e1ac131)

Comment: Please paste the code into the question as formatted text. Do not use images.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess at your intent
Looking at this method:

```
private static void printTable(int[] year, double[] celsius) {
    System.out.println("Year\tCelsius\tsDeviation");
    //for loop
   for(int i = 0; i < year.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(year[i] + "\t" + celsius[i] + "\t" + sDeviation(celsius[i]));
        }
   
  }//end printTable
```

Comment: This seems to add 0.0 along with the data that is in the file. I'm trying to take the information from a file, use it to calculate deviation and convert the data from the file to Fahrenheit as the data from the file represents Celsius, and output it as a table like: System.out.println("Deviatoin \t Celsius \t Fahrenheit");

Comment: I added the print statement. Without more info on your input file I can't begin to help you debug your deviation calculation

Comment: I updated the GitHub link to also show the input file. Hopefully, that will help to understand what I'm trying to achieve.